# Errors concerning return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am a beginner at Python, and when I try to execute this command on CMD, I was faced with this error. Please advise:

Code:

```
import re
handle=open('regex_sum_41718.txt')
for line in handle:
    word=line.split()
    print(type(word))
    y=re.findall('[0-9]+',word)
print(y)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Assi_1.py", line 5, in <module>
        y=re.findall('[0-9]+', word)
    File "D:\Python\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
        return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put another loop around `line.split()`:

```
for line in handle:
    for word in line.split():
        print(type(word))
        y=re.findall('[0-9]+',word)
```

Otherwise `word` is a list and only strings can be searched.